# Meteor.call with cursor argument

Tags: meteor

I have a tree structure of nodes that I need to be able to deep clone.  For security reasons (as well as performance), I'd like this to run on the server.  I created the function deepClone, which worked fine on the client, but when I changed it to a Meteor.method, crashes with a call stack range exceeded error.

The Meteor.method code:

```
Meteor.methods({
deepClone: function(oldParentNodeID, databaseName) {
if (oldParentNodeID && databaseName)
{
console.log(oldParentNodeID);
console.log(databaseName);
// oldParentNodeID is expected to be the _id of a headerNode with a field called archives[{Major:, Minor:, archivedParentNode}]
// databaseName is the name of the collection where the cloning occurs
if (!(oldParentNodeID))
{
  return;  //need to add error code
}
else
{
  var clonedTree=recursiveClone(oldParentNodeID,databaseName);
  databaseName.update({_id:oldParentNodeID},{$push: {archivedStack: clonedTree}});
}}
}});

var recursiveClone = function(currentNodeID, databaseName) {
//this function clones the node whos ID is passed and all descendents of that node.
var oldParentNode=(databaseName).findOne({_id: currentNodeID});
var archivedParentNode=new Object;
var i, childNode;
jQuery.extend(archivedParentNode,oldParentNode);
delete archivedParentNode._id;
archivedParentNode.subcategories=[];
var retval= databaseName.insert(archivedParentNode);
if ((oldParentNode.subcategories) && (oldParentNode.subcategories.length)){ 
  for (i=0; i< oldParentNode.subcategories.length; i++) {
    childNode=recursiveClone(oldParentNode.subcategories[i],databaseName);
    archivedParentNode.subcategories.push(childNode);
    databaseName.update({_id:retval},{$push: {subcategories: childNode}});
    databaseName.update({_id:childNode},{$set: {parentCategory: retval}});
  }
}
return retval;
};
```

Note that subcategories is an array of child _ids, while parentCategory is the parent's _id.

The error when I run this is:

```
RangeError {stack: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded↵   a…s?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:425:22", message: "Maximum call stack size exceeded"}
message: "Maximum call stack size exceeded"
stack: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded↵    at http://localhost:3000    /packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:424:22↵    at     Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)↵    at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:424:5)↵    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:425:22↵    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)↵    at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:424:5)↵    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:425:22↵    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)↵    at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:424:5)↵    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:425:22"
__proto__: Error
 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at http://localhost:3000/packages    /ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:424:22
at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:424:5)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:425:22
at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:424:5)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:425:22
at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
at Object.EJSON.clone (http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:424:5)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ejson.js?8659e45802513ffad53befd6dbee7e6e80df9da4:425:22
```

I suspect there's a simple fix to this, but it's eluding me.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that a node in your tree is actually pointing to one of its ancestors, resulting in an infinite loop in trying to walk the tree.

The other issue is that you'll need to make sure anything that is being stored in the database or sent over DDP can be coerced into an [EJSON](http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson) object. Otherwise, you may see this error as well.

Comment: I've checked the tree generated with the code when I ran it in the client, and it worked well.  I suspect that I have the syntax wrong to send the databaseName (collection) over DDP.  Unfortunately, I'm early in the learning curve on this.